# ASP.Net Core and model validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-core

Suppose I have a model which I need to validate. I can add some validate attributes to the properties I want to validate. And it works pretty fine. But at some point I want to validate this model depending on other models (I will need t query db). And here there are some options.

- create a special validate attribute which will lack dependency injection
- delegate this validation to some business layer (manager) and in controller

_

```
if (Model.IsValid) {
    if(!await Manager.Create(myModel)) {
        Model.CopyErrors(Manager.Errors); // Extension method for Model
    }
}
```

So what is the correct way of handling such a situation?

P.S. I am using asp.net core and entity framework core

Comment: If your validation needs to check data on db, not only if user passed numbers instead of strings you'll need something more complex. Usually, for validation that don't require database, use fluent validation as suggested. Is the most straightforward way to go and every dev knows about it. Don't reinvent the wheel yourself.

Comment: The second level of validation you could have is having decorators around your Manager.Create method. I assume Manager is sort of a repository or other layer. Using Autofac for instance, you can register Decorators around your repository and when you call Create, the decorator chain will execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [Fluent Validation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/i.-ASP.NET-Core-integration)

Comment: in fact I don't want to use third-party validation library. I want to know how it should be handled with what I have

Comment: @arthur.borisow up to you, but `Fluent Validation` is de facto for handling complex validation tasks in asp.net mvc.